# Validation rule on a text field based on Role

Tags: administration, community, validation

I want to create a validation rule on a look up field based on role . There are two roles

1. Member Member  - is a member
2. Member PA - is a pa to the member

lookup fields - REP_Customer_Representative__c (lookup to Account)

The requirement is when a **"member member"** creates a case and if the look up field is blank the validation rule should not fire as *REP_Customer_Representative__c - is a member representing field*

But when a **"Member Pa"** creates a case he/she should not leave the lookup field *REP_Customer_Representative__c  - blank*

and this is what i came up with, but the validation rule is not getting fired

```
AND( ISBLANK(REP_Customer_Representative__c), 
$UserRole.Name = 'Member_PA' )
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question? It is hard to understand (at least for me :))

Comment: i want to create a validation rule on a look up field based on role .

Comment: Are you sure that is the UserRole Name? It looks more like a Developer Name with the underscore.

Comment: Agreed. The Name should generally be the human-readable name: `'Member PA'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer, but try:

```
AND( ISBLANK(REP_Customer_Representative__r.Id), 
$UserRole.Name = 'Member_PA' )
```

I seem to recall the validation rules needing to look up a value on the parent (i.e. `REP_Customer_Representative__r.Id`), not just where there is a value in that field itself.

Let us know if this works... or not.